# Create a login page using EF WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, mvvm

I'm creating a login page to enable a user to use a `WPF` `MVVM` application. So far I'm using `Entity Framework model`, connected to a `SQL database`.

I have one table that contains some user details such as a username, password, confirm password email and a user role.

So far, I have created a view that has been `bound` to some properties within my viewmodel (username and password).

I also have a registration page to allow a user to have a user credential (also has some validation so there can only be 1 user with a name, it can not be duplicated).

Obviously, compared to `ASP.NET` you can use authentication and create users that way. I have been following some various links how to create a login page but none of them are exactly what I would like.

But, I am not too sure what I am doing is correct, in the sense that how do I match the results from the database to allow a user to login?

This is what I have done so far;

```
public void CheckLogin()
{
     var user = context.Users.Where(i => i.UserID == this.UserID).FirstOrDefault();

     if (user != null )
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Unable to Login, incorrect credentials.");

     }
     else if (this.Username == user.Username || this.Password == user.Password)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Successfully Logged in, " + user.Username + "");
     }
     else
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Unable to Login, incorrect credentials.");
     }
}

private ICommand showLoginCommand;
public ICommand ShowLoginCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (this.showLoginCommand == null)
        {
            this.showLoginCommand = new CommandBase(i => this.CheckLogin(), null);
        }
        return this.showLoginCommand;
    }
}
```

XAML;

```
<TextBox Name="txtUserName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource myErrorTemplate}"
                 Text="{Binding Username, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="txtPassword"
               behavior:PasswordBoxAssistant.Attach="True" 
               behavior:PasswordBoxAssistant.Password="{Binding Password, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<Button Name="btnLogin" IsDefault="True" 
                    Command="{Binding ShowLoginCommand}"/>
```

But when details have been entered it doesn't seem to work. Could anyone help me create a EF statement that checks users within the database and matches it to the username and password entered from the login page?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something with the if-statement in the code. When I look at the code, it should be more like:

```
if (user == null)
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Unable to Login, incorrect credentials.");

 }
 else if (this.Username == user.Username && this.Password == user.Password)
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Successfully Logged in, " + user.Username + "");
 }
 else
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Unable to Login, incorrect credentials.");
 }
```

If the user not exists, show the message and the username **and** password must be equal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @NRonald, I have also tried that previous to my question and still doesn't seem to work either. It still breaks to the else statement, and cant not find the users that are already within the database.

Comment: The user is collected from the database using the UserID. Maybe is does not correspond with Username and password. Also check if there not a case (upper/lower case) difference in the values.

Comment: Thanks fort he reply. I gathered that it was to do with the ID, but not sure what I should do to find the username by its userID. Any ideas how using EF?

Comment: If only the username and password are entered, it should be more like: `var user = context.Users.Where(i => i.Username == this.Username).SingleOrDefault();` and then check if password is correctly entered.

Comment: Hi NRonald, that seems to query the username much better, much appreciated! But due to the fact that I using the code in the VM, when it does match, It doesn;t close the window.